# *Kernel Hacking* option not listed on RHEL 8.3

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel

make menuconfig  not showing *Kernel Hacking* option ( kernel version 5.12) , while trying to build the kernel.

Step 1 : Copied .config file to kernel source directory.

Step 2 : make menuconfig

[menu of make menuconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NhKY.jpg)

Packages like " Development Tools" , ncurses-devel, bison, flex, elfutils-libelf-devel openssl-devel already installed.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Try asking in Unix & Linux StackExchange.  SO is for programming questions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question.

Comment: Kbuild questions are not programming questions?  Surely they are.